# Does the Wizarding world holds elections

Tags: harry-potter

Is the *Ministry of Magic* elected? Is the (British) magical world a democracy? What political parties exist? How are elections organized? How frequent does one can/have to vote?

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, we learn that *Albus Dumbledore* was offered the post of Minister for Magic three times. This seems to imply one at least doesn't have to volunteer to get elected?